# Discord.py guild invite bot

Tags: python, discord.py

If the code is correct, I want to make a bot where the bot invites me to a specific server.
but it has error.

Here's my code:

```
@client.command()
async def invite(ctx, *, code):
    if code == "12320001":
        guild = "851841115896152084"
        invite = await ctx.guild.create_invite(max_uses=1)
        await ctx.send(f"Here's your invite : {invite}")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Code is wrong!")
```

and error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_invite'
```

Answer (score 1):

`ctx.guild` is `None`, that is why you are getting this Exception.

You can check the value of `ctx.guild` before passing `ctx` as a parameter while calling `invite` function.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, `ctx.guild` is `None`. This usually occurs when invoking a command in a DM rather than in a server, as there obviously is no server in DMs.

Judging by the fact that you have a `guild` variable that you never used I assume that you're trying to invite people to *that* guild instead.

```py
# Make sure the id is an int, NOT a string
guild = client.get_guild(85184111589615208)

# Invite users to the guild with the above id instead
invite = await guild.create_invite(max_uses=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Channel` object to create an invite as the `Guild` class doesn't have a `create_invite()` method. You can the code given below. Note that the server should have at least one channel.

```py
@client.command()
async def invite(ctx, code):
    if code == "12320001":
        guild = client.get_guild(851841115896152084)
        invite = await guild.channels[0].create_invite(max_uses = 1)
        await ctx.send(f"Here's your invite: {invite}")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Invalid code!")
```

Comment: @Tamong, please mark this answer as the solution if it helped.